# I can't get custom tableviewcell's contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I'm developing application.

I make a custom UITableViewCell.

But I can't get custom tableviewcell's contents.

For example, here's my custom UITableViewCell's image.

[image]

TextEditorCell.h

```
...

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

...
```

AddNewObject.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _textEditor = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Text"];
    _datePicker = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Date"];
    SwitchCell *_switch = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Switch"];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return _textEditor;
    }else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        return _datePicker;
    }else{
        _switch.titleLabel.text = @"Main Countdown";
        return _switch;
    }

    return nil;
}
...
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Text:%@",_textEditor.textField.text);
}
```

Log

```
2013-12-27 23:47:58.498 Application[10039:80b] Text:(null)
```

I wrote a sentence.

But log is null.

why?

Comment: The problem is inside your action method TextEditorCell class does not initialzed properly. So you need to check whether its object exist or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
TextEditorCell *cell = (TextEditorCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *text = cell.textField.text;
NSLog(@"Text:%@",text);
```

I thank every answerer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cell is a View and it shouldn't store any data. I assume that your `IBAction` is inside your custom cell class. So if you want to pass the parameters in there (even on the same class) you have to unfortunately set your property to `strong`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```